# mysql loader error? 'C:test.txt' not found (Errcode: 2)

Tags: mysql, import

I tried the following code to load data from text document (file name is `test.txt`) to MySQL database, but it shows an error:

> File 'C:test.txt' not found (Errcode: 2)

The query is:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:test.txt' INTO TABLE messagebox  fields terminated by ','  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` __'C:test.txt'__ `INTO TABLE`

Answer (score 3):

modify your drive address to `C:\\test.txt`

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\test.txt'
```

`INTO TABLE 'messagebox'`

```
fields terminated by ',' fields escaped by '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Comment: I have a question here: Is the last line in the answer for specifying paths or for the content of the txt file?

Answer (score 1):

@Skyrel answer is perfect.In addition to that for Ubuntu users, use this command

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/user/test.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a slash in your url

```
c:\test.txt
```