# MySQL LOAD DATA Error (Errcode: 2 - "No such file or directory")

Tags: mysql, sql, bulkinsert, load-data-infile

I am trying to load data into a table of my MySQL database, and getting this error.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\Users\Myself\Desktop\Blah Blah\LOAD DATA\week.txt' 
INTO TABLE week;
```

Reference: [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html)

The path is hundred percent correct, I copied it by pressing shift and clicking "copy path as" and checked it many times. **So any tips on this will be much appreciated**. 
.
**My research:** Seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149819/mysql-loader-error-ctest-txt-not-found-errcode-2) answer, I tried by changing `C:\Users` to `C:\\Users`. It did not work for me.

Secondly, **is there a way to use some kind of a relative path (rather than an absolute path) here?**

Comment: If given as a relative path name, the name is interpreted relative to the directory in which the client program was started. [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what version of MySQL you are using but a quick Google search found possible answers to both your questions. Below are excerpts from the [MySQL 5.1 Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html):

> The file name must be given as a literal string. On Windows, specify
>   backslashes in path names as forward slashes or doubled backslashes
>
> The LOCAL keyword affects where the file is expected to be found:
>
> If LOCAL is specified, the file is read by the client program on the
>   client host and sent to the server. The file can be given as a full
>   path name to specify its exact location. If given as a relative path
>   name, the name is interpreted relative to the directory in which the
>   client program was started.

Regards.

Answer (score 7):

I spent 2 days on this and finally got my mistake, Just changing backslashes by forward ones, as one contributor previously said. And finally worked for me. 
so was:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Data/menagerie/pet.txt' INTO TABLE pet;
```

I just can say thanks a lot.

p.s. don't waste time on ytb...

Answer (score 2):

If using MySQL Workbench on a local Windows PC to connect to a remote MySQL server,

1. Add the "LOCAL" keyword
2. Add double backslashes "\\" to your folder path

If text file's first row has column names add "IGNORE 1 LINES".

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\MyTabDelimited.txt'
INTO TABLE my_table IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace backslash with slash in the path.
This works for me (MySQL Workbench 6.3 on Win 10):

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/Users/Myself/Desktop/Blah Blah/LOAD DATA/week.txt' 
INTO TABLE week;
```

Ref. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/loading-tables.html

Answer (score 1):

One more reason for this type of error is another languge in the path.
You might have almost the entire path in English, but the username might be auto-filled in another language.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the word `LOCAL` from your query.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the week.txt file to the desktop

then execute in a terminal window:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\Users\Myself\Desktop\week.txt' 
INTO TABLE week;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using double backslash That slash is also worked for me too.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem by replacing the path

Replace format                              `"C:\Users\Myself\Desktop\week.txt"`

With this different format                  `"C:/Users/Myself/Desktop/week.txt"`

My computer didnt recognize the `( \ )` symbols.